# Gravity in stationary space

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, free-body-diagram

Since 95% of the Earth's gravity remains even at an altitude of 100 miles from the surface, a spacecraft in orbit maintains balance between Earth's gravity & centrifugal force.  While in orbit, the spacecraft is constantly falling back to Earth...astronauts experience weightlessness.
But if the spacestation or spacecraft were held stationary by say hovering or continuous supply of thrust in all directions. Would there be gravity for them to walk?

Comment: FYI: Take that same spacecraft, place it somewhere deep in intergalactic space, hundreds of thousands of light years from any galaxy, and then turn on the engine with the same exact throttle setting: The people inside will be able to walk around, and they will feel the exact same 0.95g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle

Answer (score 2):

Yes. As you said, it would be about $0.95 \ g$. This would definitely be sufficient gravity for walking